# Separating HTTP and game server traffic to the same address

Tags: http, redirect, minecraft

We have two dedicated servers. Server 1 is running Linux CentOS and acts as our webserver. Server 2 is running Windows Server 2008 mostly hosting services such as gameservers and does not have apache or anything installed.

Server 1 is hosting the website minecraft.nl. We were also running our Minecraft server on Server 1. This way you could join our server by typing in "minecraft.nl" in the address bar ingame.

Because of performance issues our Minecraft server is forced to move from Server 1 to Server 2. Problem is, that then can't join our server any more by typing in "minecraft.nl" which I think is a big plus when pulling in players. The only solution I see right now is making a subdomain like "play.minecraft.nl" and have that redirect to Server 2, but that's not exactly what I want.

So is there a way to keep the game server and website on the same address (minecraft.nl), but direct the connection to either Server 1 or Server 2 based on whether the website or game server is contacted?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like iptables should work to forward the port for minecraft out to server 2.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d {server1ip} --dport {minecraftport} -j DNAT --to-destination {server2ip}:{minecraftport}
```

You may need to read up on iptables some more, I don't use them often, one of those things once you set it up you don't usually have to mess with it again. the above iptables command may be able to get it done.  Just replace the tokens with what you need